# JavaScript: Pass Google Sheet cell value as Variable into POST URL

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, post, google-sheets-api

So I have this code that is supposed to fetch a project_id from a google sheet and append it into URL. I have added the plus (+) but still unable to pick the project_id from the google sheet. Posting will not be possible without this parameter. It is not throwing any error but still unable to post to the project's system. Here is the code: What am I not doing right?

```
 function sendBudget(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();  
  // used getLastRow() function [1] to narrow the array to have only cells with data.
  var range = sheet.getRange("AO2:AO"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var searchString = "3";

  for (var i = 0; i<range.length; i++) {
    if(range[i][0] == searchString) {
      var lastRow = sheet.getRange(2+i,1,1,41).getValues(); 
      var project_id = lastRow[0][40];
      var data = {

        'amount':lastRow[0][7]*10,


      };
      var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
      var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'payload' : data,
      };
      var url = 'https://vnext.10000ft.com/api/v1/projects/'+ project_id +'/budget_items?item_type=TimeFeesDays&auth=token';
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , options);
      if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
      var json = JSON.parse(response);
      var id = json["id"];
      sheet.getRange(2+i, 41).setValue(4); 
      }
    else { 
      sheet.getRange(2+i, 41).setValue(5);
    }
  }
  }}
```

Comment: Hello @levi your code doesn't seem to have any programming error. May I ask you to share the Sheet you are using? At least, could you describe at which column of your Sheet are the project ids and how are they laid out? Further to that, you could try using `Logger.log(url)` right after creating your `url`, in order to print it and possibly find what is going on. Cheers

Comment: Hi @carlesgg97, apparently I had used the wrong row number when defining the variable project_id and had not noticed this. After you told me about the sheet, I went back and did manual count and realized it was supposed to be var project_id = lastRow[0][39];. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the project_id was picking the wrong cell, so all did change is the row number in the variable:

```
var project_id = lastRow[0][40];
```